# How to detect vertically stacked text with vision API

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, google-vision, vision-api

Basic text detection API (e.g. google) does not return anything for the following image. To try Google's vision API, save the image locally and run:

```
gcloud ml vision detect-text <local-path-to-image> | grep description
```

It may return gibberish. The text we want is RAW9405. Are there any existing models for this or does it require training?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use craft-text-detector which is available opensource, you will get the bounding box coordinates for every `single word` and based on y-axis you can form a sentence than use `tesseract` for recognition.